# How to install github cli extension in a custom folder?

Tags: windows, github

I have installed github cli on my Windows 11 machine. Then I installed copilot extension by following the instruction at [Github copilot extension](https://docs.github.com/en/copilot/github-copilot-in-the-cli/using-github-copilot-in-the-cli), that is,

```
gh extension install github/gh-copilot
```

It installs copilot extension in C:\Users<username>\AppData\Local\GitHub CLI folder. I would like to install it in a different folder, say C:\Users\experimental_stuff\GitHub CLI folder.

I am not able to find a way to change the installation path for GitHub Cli extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the only way it worked.

1. Uninstall GitHub CLI copilot extension.
2. Open Regedit. Navigate to Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Volatile Environment
3. Update the Key LOCALAPPDATA, with Value data  C:\Users\experimental_stuff\GitHub CLI
4. Re-install GitHub CLI copilot extension.

Answer (score 0):

Generally programs and like apps go in Program Folders and like places like that (AppData). That is so Apps can be set up normally (locations, permissions).

This is likely the reason you cannot change it to (your example of) a non-program folder.

Otherwise, the people who wrote the app would have to provide a reason.